# Bootstrap: 'TypeError undefined is not a function'/'has no method 'tab'' when using bootstrap-tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a little site at the moment and wanted to use some of the Bootstrap parts from Initialzr, specifically the tabs. I've currently tried using the example code provided by the Bootstrap project (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) and a few tweaks but get 'undefined is not a function' on load.

The JS files are preloaded in the right order (jQuery, libs/bootstrap/*, my script.js file/the script mixed in the html), standard jQuery commands (hide etc) all work fine so it doesn't appear to be related to the noConflict() option.

What else do I need to check?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you trying to use?

Comment: @periklis: using 2.0 from Initializr

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: Popovers require the tooltip plugin as a dependency. So include it first.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I actually managed to work out what I was doing wrong (and it was my fault).

I'm used to using pre-jQuery Rails, so when I included the Bootstrap JS files I didn't think that including the version of jQuery bundled with them would cause any issues, however when I removed that one JS file everything started working perfectly.

Lesson learnt, triple check which JS files are loaded, see if there's any conflicts.

Comment: Ditto, we had a similar problem, and it turned out an old JS file was being included.

Comment: It'd help if the error was more descriptive, but I guess that's what SO is for :)

Comment: Upgrading from jQuery 1.6.2 to jQuery 1.7.2 sorted it for me.

Answer (score 82):

This can also be caused if you include `bootstrap.js` before `jquery.js`.

Others might have the same problem I did.

Include `jQuery` before `bootstrap`.

Comment: not working for me `//= require lib/jquery-2.1.0.min
//= require lib/bootstrap.min`

Answer (score 18):

make sure you're **using the newest jquery**, and problem solved

I met this problem with this code:

```
<script src="/scripts/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"> </script>
<script src="/scripts/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

After change it to this:

```
<script src="/scripts/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> </script>
<script src="/scripts/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

It works fine

Comment: Isnt there a way to use Bootstrap plugins with jQuery 1.6.2 ? We have used jQuery alot in our project and upgrading to 1.7.2 is breaking few things so we dont wish to upgrade it till next release. However we wish to include few of the plugins (Typeahead and Tooltips) in our App. Is there a way to use them with jQuery 1.6.2. Any idea if anybody has created its equivalent that works with older versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Probably is the use of the "on" event that Bootstrap use a lot and was inserted at jQuery 1.7
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

We can try by using latest jQuery library. I got the same issue. I used jQuery-1.4.2.min before and getting the error. After that I used version 1.9.1 and it works. Thanks